# c++ (for) loop :calculating y=n/(n+1)!

Tags: c++, loops

Write a program to solve the following equation

```
 Y=1/2!‐2/3!+3/4!‐4/5!+….n/(n+1)!
```

The negative sign confuse me and there is a factorial sign too !
is it like the program should have factorial and do i have to subtract numbers from numbers ?

```
int n,a;
double b=2,y,sum=0;
cin>>n;
for (a=1;a<=n;a++)
{
    y=a/b++;
    sum=sum+y;
}
cout<<y<<endl<<sum;
return 0;
```

Comment: are you asking us to explain the assignment?

Comment: i want to know how to make the subtraction it is confusing ..

Comment: If you're going to ask us to do your homework at least use proper English.

Comment: sure i didn't ask u to do my HW ! i was looking for explanation =)

Comment: Hint: If you multiply 1 by -1 you get -1. If you multiply -1 by -1 you get 1. `k - x` is the same as `k + -1 * x`.

Comment: @molbdnilo thanks a lot for the help ..,now i figure it out ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In many math scenarios, the '-' or what you are calling the *negative* sign, also works as subtraction.

You have two options:

1. Negate the value then add.
2. Subtract the value.

By order of precedence, you need to figure out the factorial of the denominator, divide the numerator by the denominator, and finally add or *subtract* from the total.

**Edit 1:**
Another solution is to process two terms per iteration.  Add the first, subtract the second.

```
double term1 = 0.0;
double term2 = 0.0;
double result = 0.0;

for (...)
{
  term1 = /*...*/;
  term2 = /*...*/;'
  result = result + term1;
  result = result - term2;
}
```

Or you can have a sign variable and multiply the term by the sign variable:

```
double sign = 1.0;
double result = 0.0;
for (...)
{
  double term = /* ... */;
  result = result + sign * term;
  sign = sign * -1.0;
}
```